# "Join expression not supported" for multiple Left Join in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I have the following query which I am passing as a string in my ASP.NET project:

```
SELECT creditorName, amount, interestRate, interestType, interestCalculationMethod, insertedDate, o.fullName AS owner, u.fullName AS dataInsertedBy FROM ((tbl_savings s) LEFT JOIN tbl_users o ON (ownerID = o.userID)) LEFT JOIN tbl_users u ON (dataEnteredByID = u.userID);
```

for which I am getting the following error:

```
+       $exception  {"Join expression not supported."}  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
```

I am using MS Access 2016 as the database.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on MSDN. Here's the link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev

I apologize for not putting in the correct answer along with the link that I posted. Here is the correct answer:

```
select savingsID, creditorName, amount, interestRate, 
    interestType, interestCalculationMethod, insertedDate,
    ownerID, o.fullName as owner,
    u.fullName as dataEnteredBy
from (
   (tbl_savings as s)
   left join tbl_users as o on s.ownerID = o.userID
) left join tbl_users as u on s.dataEnteredByID = u.userID
```